# Path to create a file in domain folder of website

Tags: model-view-controller

I want to create a text file in a folder of my project. Locally every thing is fine but when I upload my site to a domain then it throws exception that the path access is denied. What should I do to avoid this exception?Thanks.

Comment: What are you hosting your site on?

Comment: a single web page...and one button on that page create a text file on the server or in the folder which have hosted site...

Comment: What what language are you writing in, what server are you using, and what OS is that server running on?